# Django Datatables view

Tags: django, datatables

Im trying to convert my tables in my django app to [datatables using django-tables2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html).

Im my `campaigns.py` view I have:

```
class CampaignListView(FacebookAdInit):
    """ CampaignListView for viewing all the campaigns"""

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ad_account = self.get_ad_account(kwargs.get('ad_account_id'))

        campaigns = self.get_campaigns(ad_account.get('id')) \
            if ad_account else None
        context = {'campaigns': campaigns, 'ad_account': ad_account}

        return render(request, 'app/campaigns/index.html', context)
```

Im my `campaigns/index.html` I have:

```
{% extends "app/empty_page.html" %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% block content %}
            {% if ad_account %}
                        {% render_table context  %}
            {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

However this gives me the error: `Expected table or queryset, not 'str'.`
ANy help will be greately appreciated.

Right now I generate the table using this piece of code:

```
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="campaigns">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> #</th>
                        <th> Campaign Name</th>
                        <th> Campaign Objective</th>
                        <th> Campaign Effective Status</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for campaign in campaigns %}
                        <tr>
                            <td> {{ forloop.counter }} </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/ad_accounts/{{ ad_account.id }}/campaigns/{{ campaign.id }}/ad_sets">
                                    {{ campaign.name }} </a>
                            </td>
                            <td> {{ campaign.objective }}</td>
                            <td> {{ campaign.effective_status }} </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: Post entire traceback please?

Comment: Traceback shows what I posted. The error message and the `{% render_table context %}` line is highlited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a `Table` instance or queryset to the `render_table` tag.

```
{% render_table campaigns %}
```

Comment: Thats a start. However nothing is generated i.e. I see an empty page ( debug shows no errors)

Comment: Sorry, I can't spot any other issues. Your question includes lots of stuff that you haven't show (e.g `self.get_campaigns(ad_account.get('id')`) so the problem might be somewhere else. Try and get a really simple version working first, like the tutorial does. For example, use `Campaign.objects.all()[:10]` for the queryset, and don't use any template inheritance until you're sure it's working).

Comment: Your code does not show anything that would be trying to access `ad_accounts` (with an 's'). Your views and templates only contain `ad_account`.

Comment: This seems to be a new question, it isn't related to django-tables2 any more. You've posted lots of code, but you haven't explained what is causing the error or what the error is.